# How can I add a comma at the end of every line except the last line?

Tags: bash, sed, command-line

I want add a comma at the end of every line of this kind of file except the last line:

I have this now:

```
{...}
{...}
{...}
{...}
```

I want this:

```
{...},
{...},
{...},
{...}
```

How can I do it with the command line? Is it possible with sed command?

Comment: That won't make it valid JSON.

Comment: you might be calling your JSON from foreach loop, so its not possible without `preg_replace`

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The following `sed` script has an address expression `$!` which matches lines which are not the last, and a substituton action `s/$/,/` which adds a comma next to the end of line.

```
sed '$!s/$/,/' file
```

(The `$` in the address refers to the last *line* while the `$` in the regular expression in the substitution refers to the last *character position* on every line.  They are unrelated, though in some sense similar.)

This prints the modified contents of `file` to standard output; redirect to a different file to save them to a file, or use `sed -i` if your `sed` supports that. (Some variants require an empty argument to the `-i` option, notably *BSD / OSX `sed`.)

If your task is to generate valid JSON from something which is not, I'm skeptical of this approach.  Structured formats should be manipulated with tools which understand structured formats, not basic line-oriented tools; but if this helps you transform line-oriented data towards proper JSON, that's probably a valid use.

... As an afterthought, maybe you want to wrap the output in a set of square brackets, too. Then it's actually technically valid JSON (assuming each line is a valid JSON fragment on its own).

```
sed '1s/^/[/;$!s/$/,/;$s/$/]/' file
```

On the first line (address expression `1`) substitute in an opening square bracket at beginning of line (`s/^/[/`).  On lines which are not the last, add a trailing comma, as above. On the line which *is* the last (address expression `$`) add a closing square bracket at the end of line (`s/$/]/`).  If you prefer newlines to semicolons, that's fine; many `sed` dialects also allow you to split this into multiple `-e` arguments.

Comment: I want with -i but not works, is this the correct command?  `sed -i '$!s/$/,/' file`

Comment: Awesome! I made a little script with this trick to export a JSON line file to a JSON file, calling it like this `./jl2json.sh sample.jsonl sample.json`. Take a look here https://gist.github.com/mrsarm/24e8531ef8375c768e03d1c1aea67262

Answer (score 14):

```
vim <file-name>

:%s/$/,/g
```

To remove

```
:%s/,//g
```

Answer (score 8):

Keep it simple, just use awk:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s",sep,$0; sep=",\n"} END{print ""}' file
{...},
{...},
{...},
{...}
```

Comment: Keep it simple? The sed answer seems significantly simpler to me.

Comment: No, it's just briefer. Think about the logic - find the last line and don't apply a substitution. What? It's like trying to use Prolog. Now try to enhance that to do just about anything else  and you'll be knee deep in double negatives and bizarre convolutions of letters and punctuation marks before you know it.

Comment: Sed: "every line except the last, find the end and add a comma." Simple. Awk: "every line print the separator and then the line, (wait, why the separator first?) then set the separator (why include the newline? Oh, must be a record separator...), then at the very end, print an empty line (what? Oh, the backwards RS/record printing doesn't leave a trailing newline)." You have an odd definition of "simple."

Comment: You are trying to make this WAY more complicated than it is. None of the awk statements reads quite the way you state, and they all mean the same simple, obvious thing that's been programmed as such for decades in every Algol-based language (C, Pascal, Ada, whatever) - hold off on printing the end of line string until you print the subsequent line because that is when you know what to print at the end of the line. Nothing at all to do with "backwards RS" and "record printing doesn't leave a trailing newline". I guess we'll agree to disagree - happy sed-ing!

Comment: You might need some conditional code in the END block to cater for empty files.

Comment: Yup, couldn't hurt. If the OP wants it I can add that.

Comment: The reason this is a little unintuitive is that it's taking advantage of the fact that `awk` doesn't care if a variable is undefined, it just treats it as empty. So, when the first line is processed, there is no 'sep', so you don't end up with a line at the beginning with just a comma on it (as you might expect from a simple reading of this script.

Comment: This answer helped me A LOT because I'm already in an awk program, so the sed approach was not an option. Thanks, Ed!