# Bash - How to export VSCode extensions to a .sh file in the following format?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, automation

Format:

```sh
code --install-extension adpyke.codesnap --force &
code --install-extension alefragnani.Bookmarks --force &
code --install-extension arturock.gitstash --force &
code --install-extension csholmq.excel-to-markdown-table --force
```

Currently, I'm doing `code --list-extensions | xargs -L 1 echo code --install-extension > install-extensions.sh` to get the extensions printed to `install-extensions.sh` and manually add `--force &` at end of lines in that file, that's the furthest I can get.

I'm not very familiar with the bash syntax, could anyone please shed some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some diggings, I finally got it working, the working script:

```sh
code --list-extensions |
xargs -L 1 echo code --install-extension |
sed 's/$/ --force/' |
sed '$!s/$/ \&/' > install-extensions.sh
```

Reference: [How can I add a comma at the end of every line except the last line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35021524/how-can-i-add-a-comma-at-the-end-of-every-line-except-the-last-line/35021663)